# Normalization on 2 dimensions

Tags: standardization

I have alot of stock data features.  I have normalized each feature by stock as different stocks have very different stdev.  I would also like to normalize by time of day.  IE stdev is very different at 9:45AM than at Noon.  How do I standarized for two dimentions rather than just one?  Do I do two passes?  Is there another better way?  I created some mock data and saw that 2 passes does skew the signal toward the low stdev.

Comment: Could you indicate *why* you want the normalization to vary by time of day?  What do you hope this would accomplish?

Comment: So one feature is the return over the last 5 min.  The returns during the first 15 min of the market have a much larger stdev than later in the day.  So if I wanted to look at all stocks greater than a 2 z-score, they would almost all be in the first 15 min of the trading day. A 2-dimention normalization would allow a 2 z-score to occur just as equally later in the day as earlier in the day.

Comment: Sure--that's what it would do *mathematically.*  But why would that help your model?  What are you hoping the model will do?  After all, if you were to take this to the limit of very tiny time windows, you would eliminate all variation in the values, erasing almost all the information in them!